# Looping input command

Tags: shell, date, input, format

How can we have input from user in `DD/MM/YYYY` format in shell code such that till user does not provides input in this format the same prompt is printed again and again.

```
printf "Please Enter START Date(DD/MM/YYYY)\n"
read date1
```

how to check in this that if date is provided in DD/MM/YYYY format or not. and if not then how to start this loop again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution firstly checks the syntax of all the tokens
of the input and then using the command `date` checks if the
the input is a valid date. For instance 30/02/2014 has 
a correct syntax but it is not a valid date. Please note
that the `date` command accepts the format MM/DD/YYYY.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
    IFS="/" read -p "Please Enter START Date(DD/MM/YYYY): " d m y

    if [[ $d != [0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo "Day format invalid"; continue; fi
    if [[ $m != [0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo "Month format invalid"; continue; fi
    if [[ $y != [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo "Year format invalid"; continue; fi

    if date -d "$m/$d/$y" > /dev/null; then
            date1="$d/$m/$y"
            break
    fi

done

# Here you can use $date1 as you prefer. For instance:
echo $date1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
until read -p "Please Enter START Date (DD/MM/YYYY): " && [[ $REPLY == [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] ]]; do
    ## echo "Please enter in proper (DD/MM/YYYY) format."
    continue
done
```

The echo part is just optional that you could consider adding.
By default, read places input in $REPLY variable if no variable is specified, but you could have a custom one if you like.

```
read -p "Please Enter START Date (DD/MM/YYYY): " INPUT && [[ $INPUT == ...
```

For a bit more sh-compatible and based on your own format you can have this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
    printf "Please Enter START Date(DD/MM/YYYY)\n"
    read date1
    case "$date1" in
    [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9])
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: @By the way for the second example it should have been `[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]` not `[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]` sorry. And you're welcome..